# Nginx proxy stops working after a while

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have 2 loadbalanced frontend servers running on Amazon AWS. Both have nginx installed on it. Loadbalancer used is Amazon ELB.

There are 2 loadbalanced backend servers. This app is a ruby on rails app. And it uses nginx/unicorn.

The frontend servers proxy to backend server for API calls. Everything works fine but after some time the proxy stops working.

Here is the nginx conf of frontend servers:
[nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/B1UFMPew)
[vhost](http://pastebin.com/JpLNLPPG)
and one more [conf](http://pastebin.com/qa1HnxR0) for setting up a variable.

Can someone explain whats the issue? And why after sometime the proxy stops working from both frontend servers?

Comment: well you didn't explain how it "stops" exactly, do you get an error 500 ? 502 ? unable to connect?

Comment: The proxy doesnt happen. I get 502. The requests dont reach to nginx/unicorn app.

Comment: Could be related to this: http://serverfault.com/questions/560632/some-nginx-reverse-proxy-configs-stops-working-once-a-day